# Correct usage of sentences

Tags: prepositions, sentence-structure, questions

Which of the following is correct?

> Your grammar is so good. **Why** do you need a grammar book **for**?

or

> Your grammar is so good. **What** do you need a grammar book **for**?

Comment: The latter is correct, you can rephrase it like this "For what do you need a grammar book".

Comment: @user178049 - You could, but what would you want to rephrase it like that for?

Comment: @J.R. I want to show that *what* actually refers to the complement of the preposition. And I don't think *why* makes sense if it's used like that.

Comment: @user178049: I would describe **why** as **for what reason**... but only to explain the difference between the two sentences. In practice, **why** is a much more convenient way of saying it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP explains how they want the question answered, and their suggested approach is probably not the best way of explaining the difference.

Comment: It might be useful to compare 1: *What did you ask?* and 2: *What did you ask for?* The first one simply asks you to clarify/repeat whatever your request was (maybe you wanted to know if the moon is made of green cheese, or whether someone would marry you). But the second one is ambiguous - it could mean the speaker wants to know ***why** you asked a question*, or it could mean he wants to know ***what specific thing*** you requested be given to you (by implication, something "real", as opposed to simply *an answer to a question*). But note that *Why did you ask for?* is simply ungrammatical.

Comment: Oh grammar book, grammar book.  Whyfore art thou useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*What for* is a set phrase meaning:

> for what purpose or reason

([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/what%20for)). Basically it means the same thing as *why*.

You can either say:

> **What** do you need a grammar book **for**?

or

> **Why** do you need a grammar book?

Aside from JR's example in the comments, you can find more example sentences at:

[LDOCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/what-for), [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/what?q=what+...+for) or [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/what-for?q=what+...+for).

To make the usage of *what ... for?* clearer, you might ask yourself how would you answer such a question. For instance:

> Why did you stop at Tom's office? (What did you stop at Tom's office for?)

You can reply: *I stopped at his office to have a chat about our marketing strategy*, but you can also say:

> I stopped at his office **for** a chat about our marketing strategy.

([BBC Learning English](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv284.shtml))